# How to change Shutter's image saving path?

Tags: shutter

Shutter natively stores images under `/home/user/pictures/`.

How could I change this path to just `/home/desktop/` ?

Found no such option in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate with the mouse to system tray (upper right corner of the screen).
2. Right click Shutter icon.
3. Click "Preferences".
4. You will already be under the tab "main".
5. There, Under the "directory" option, change it to Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Open shutter
2. Move cursor to top
3. Select menu **Edit** > **Preferences**
4. Choose Main, and then change Directory
5. Close

   [image: shutter]

Comment: silent install / automation people: settings are stored inside `~/.shutter/...` (yes, outside `~/.config`)